# Changing CSRF Failure HTTP Response Code in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

We're using laravel 5.3's built in csrf protection via `{{ csrf_field() }}` method.

When we've been running security scans that are obviously failing, the server is returning a `500 Internal Server Error`

However this isn't actually a server error - as it is the client sending bad information - thus it should fall into the 400 Error range.

I've done a small bit of digging and cant quite see how it actually returns the 500.

Would anybody be able to suggest how to change this response to something else?

Comment: what is your web server apache or Nginx? sometime this error come with apache server this can be solve by change some configuration on apache server.

Comment: Its apache run through an nginx proxy - however we're not worried about why its erroring, we know this, we're just wanting to change the status code that returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override this through your `App/Http/Middleware/VerifyCSRFToken.php` file like so:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        try {
            return parent::handle($request, $next);
        } catch (TokenMismatchException $ex) {
            // throw custom exception like so: throw new CustomException($ex->getMessage());
            // or new HttpException with response code like so: abort(403, $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it happens, there was no message from the exception, so we added `return abort(403, 'CSRF Token Mismatch - Please try submit the form again or contact us immediately.');`

Comment: If you throw a custom exception, where would you catch it to handle it, to say, return a json response, or display a view for example.

Comment: @Andrew all application exceptions can be catched using Handler.php. Refer the doc page [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors)

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.3 you go to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and edit the `render()` function.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        //do some stuff here.
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I'm sure this works, however as we're using sentry and have extra logic already in our render functions we decided keep all the logic in the csrf middleware rather than splitting between 2 places :)